# Removing &nbsp; from iOS notification Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification

I have a problem with notfication in my Flutter app on iOS system. I am receiving push notifications which include `&nbsp;` Unfortunately the notification text could not be edited from backend so I need to find a way to get rid of this.

Is there any part in iOS app files of the code where I can remove that and display notification without `&nbsp;`?

[notification with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLp1T.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Flutter's String object has `replacceAll` function.
So in your case will be

```
String cleanText = yourFlutterVariable.replaceAll('&nbsp;', ' ');
```

Comment: Yes but works only for in app text where I display all notification. The notification that is displayed by iOS system on notification bar is still the same with &nbsp;

Comment: This may not be Flutter related question. You notifications are generated by Firebase i guess ? I have a Flutter app fed by Firestore my self and before pushing the content to Firestore I clean the html content on my PHP server.  May be you will get more accurate feedback if you reword the title and mention which server stack you use to generate the content?